# How do I serialize an object with a string value that contains an ampersand?

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to create a table using Xml/Xslt, where some of the cells are empty, but IE formats the empty cell as invisible.  Here is an example of a cell object that is a pretty simplified version of what I'm dealing with:

```
    public class Cell
    {
         public value;

         public Cell(string value){ this.value = value; }
    }
```

So if I have a bunch of cells in a table, I'm setting `value = &#160;` when a given cell is empty or null, so that displaying that cell in IE will show an empty cell rather than no cell at all.

The problem is that the string `&#160;` is always translated to `&amp;#160;` when I serialize the object.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the actual character (`"\u0160"`).
The XML serializer should correctly entitize that.

Comment: This is giving me the character Š

Comment: Then you probably want a different character.

Comment: This turned out to be basically right, I must've made some mistake with the encoding though. "\u00A0" worked for me. Thanks so much for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [HttpUtility](http://www.dotnetperls.com/httputility) methods to decode your string after the serialization. i.e:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace htmlencode
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("&#160;");
            var decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&amp;#160;");
            Console.WriteLine("Encoded: " + encoded); //Prints &amp;#160;
            Console.WriteLine("Decoded: " + decoded); //Prints &#160;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```